# Beyond Linux from scratch 11.3 p11-kit not installing using Freebl library

Tags: lfs, nss

I am going through the BLFS manual. I installed p11-kit-0.24.1 successfully. I then went on to install NSS-3.88.1 also successfully. When I went back to install p11-kit to make use of NSS, ninja failed.

p11 build process (using NSS):
extracted tar
cd into directory

```
mkdir p11-build &&
cd    p11-build &&

meson --prefix=/usr       \
      --buildtype=release \
      -Dtrust_paths=/etc/pki/anchors \
      -Dhash_impl=freebl
```

output:

```
Run-time dependency bash-completion found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
../bash-completion/meson.build:7: WARNING: Will not install bash completion due to missing dependencies!
Build targets in project: 176

p11-kit 0.24.1

  User defined options
    buildtype  : release
    prefix     : /usr
    hash_impl  : freebl
    trust_paths: /etc/pki/anchors

Found ninja-1.11.1 at /usr/bin/ninja
WARNING: Running the setup command as `meson [options]` instead of `meson setup [options]` is ambiguous and deprecated.
```

then ran `ninja` and received `ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.`
Also received `FAILED: trust/test-digest`, `FAILED: trust/trust`, `FAILED: trust/test-x509`, and `FAILED: trust/test-index`

I'm not sure what other information is relevant but there is a huge amount of output to pull from if needed.

Thank you

(this is my first lfs/blfs build, i have a few years in computer science and Linux, but never did something this low level)

If running p11-kit with NSS is not important, than I can skip that part, but as far as I'm aware, its a pretty important step as far as security is concerned.